# Trouble with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

When I publish a program for ftp server (for example ftp://site.com/www/myprog/) and indicates that the user will download from the address http://site.com/myprog/). At first all goes well: in the folder "myprog" lies files of my program and setup.exe. But when the user launch setup.exe there is a error, because it tries to load myprog.application from site.com NOT from site.com/myprog.

Comment: can you paste the content of application file ?

Comment: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/7056/pic20120103215114.png

Comment: not the files, but the text within application file

Comment: Providing us with the sizes of your files is of no utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you actually have to specify in the ClickOnce manifest where the file is located. ClickOnce doesn't assume that the deploy location is where the app should be pulled from. Try verifying the locations in the "Publish" tab of the project's properties screen. Is everything kosher?

Comment: It's from myprog.application
< deploymentProvider codebase="http://site.com/myprog/myprog.application" / >

Comment: Hmm... Sometimes I had to run "mage.exe -cc" from my windows SDK binary folder. Does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2006/07/19/670988.aspx